# AJAX + RAILS Guardar variable javascript en my base de datos

Tags: jquery, ajax, base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails

Quiero hacer un juego tipo quiz, que según las respuestas acertadas el usuario gana X puntos. Esos x puntos quiero guardarlos en una tabla llamada Games que tiene un field llamado puntos. Me gustaría hacerlo sin tener que hacer ningún submit. Es decir, cuando el juego termina, que la puntuación quede guardada. A modo de ejemplo práctico he intentado algo de código pero me pierdo bastante. En el siguiente código he imaginado que la puntuación siempre es 4, y que cuando el usuario hace click en un botón quede la puntuación 4 guardada en la base de datos.

```jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#score').on('click',function () {

        alert("hola");
        var score=4;

        Rails.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/games/create",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: {puntos: score},
                 success: function(msg) {
                     alert("adios");
                     $('#autosavenotify').text("%SDGSFsdfs");
                 }
        })

  });
```

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  @games = Game.all

  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def create
@game=Game.new(task_params)

@game.save
  end

  private
    def task_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:puntos)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Según yo, hay dos problemas en tu código.

El primero es que hasta donde yo se el método `Rails.ajax` no existe.

Entonces allí deberías hacer algo como `$.ajax`

Y lo segundo es que tu `Controller` requiere primero un `:game` y luego dentro de éste permite solo `:puntos`. entonces debería llegar algo como esto:

`params[:game] = {puntos: "something"}`

Mira tu código, debería quedar algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#score').on('click',function () {
    var score=4;

    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/games/create",
             dataType:'json',
             data: {game: {puntos: score}},
             success: function(msg) {
                 alert("adios");
                 $('#autosavenotify').text("%SDGSFsdfs");
             }
    })
  });
});
```

Ya con eso debería funcionar, por lo menos el ejemplo que tienes. Ahora para lo que quieres hacer es simplemente cambiar el evento o ver como capturas, pero al final vaya es eso.

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: El método `Rails.ajax` existe en la librería `rails-ujs`.

Comment: Cierto, no sabia. Gracias. Nunca lo he hecho de esa forma, antes utiliza Jquery ahora lo que hago es utilizar o `fetch` o `axios`